# React Native Input onEndEditing weird callback

Tags: javascript, react-native, validation

So I try to build a form validation with React Native and the onEndEditing.

So my React Native code looks like this:

```
<TextInput onSubmitEditing={value => console.log(value)} />
```

When the user stops editing it should log the value. But instead of the log I get this:

```
{"_dispatchInstances": {"_debugHookTypes": null, "_debugID": 1400, "_debugIsCurrentlyTiming": false, 
"_debugNeedsRemount": false, "_debugOwner": {"_debugHookTypes": [Array], "_debugID": 1394, 
"_debugIsCurrentlyTiming": false, "_debugNeedsRemount": false, "_debugOwner": [FiberNode], "_debugSource": 
[Object], "actualDuration": 0, "actualStartTime": 5771, "alternate": [FiberNode], "child": [FiberNode], 
"childExpirationTime": 0, "dependencies": null, "effectTag": 517, "elementType": [Function 
InternalTextInput], "expirationTime": 0, "firstEffect": [Circular], "index": 0, "key": null, "lastEffect": 
[FiberNode], "memoizedProps": [Object], "memoizedState": [Object], "mode": 8, "nextEffect": null, 
"pendingProps": [Object], "ref": null, "return": [FiberNode], "selfBaseDuration": 0, "sibling": null, 
"stateNode": null, "tag": 0, "treeBaseDuration": 0, "type": [Function InternalTextInput], "updateQueue": 
[Object]}, "_debugSource": {"columnNumber": 7, "fileName": 
"C:\\A_USER\\App\\The_App\\\\node_modules\\react-native\\Libraries\\Components\\TextInput\\TextInput.js", 
"lineNumber": 1111}, "actualDuration": 0, "actualStartTime": 5771, "alternate": {"_debugHookTypes": null, 
"_debugID": 1400, "_debugIsCurrentlyTiming": false, "_debugNeedsRemount": false, "_debugOwner": 
[FiberNode], "_debugSource": [Object], "actualDuration": 0, "actualStartTime": 149374, "alternate": 
[Circular], "child": null, "childExpirationTime": 0, "dependencies": null, "effectTag": 132, 
"elementType": "AndroidTextInput", "expirationTime": 0, "firstEffect": null, "index": 0, "key": null, 
"lastEffect": null, "memoizedProps": [Object], "memoizedState": null, "mode": 8, "nextEffect": null, 
"pendingProps": [Object], "ref": [Function forwardRef], "return": [FiberNode], "selfBaseDuration": 0, 
"sibling": null, "stateNode": [ReactNativeFiberHostComponent], "tag": 5, "treeBaseDuration": 0, "type": 
"AndroidTextInput", "updateQueue": null}, "child": null, "childExpirationTime": 0, "dependencies": null, 
"effectTag": 132, "elementType": "AndroidTextInput", "expirationTime": 0, "firstEffect": null, "index": 0, 
"key": null, "lastEffect": null, "memoizedProps": {"accessible": true, "allowFontScaling": true, 
"autoCapitalize": "sentences", "children": undefined, "disableFullscreenUI": undefined, "focusable": true, 
"forwardedRef": null, "mostRecentEventCount": 5, "onBlur": [Function _onBlur], "onChange": [Function 
_onChange], "onChangeText": [Function onChangeText], "onClick": [Function onClick], "onEndEditing": 
[Function onEndEditing], "onFocus": [Function _onFocus], "onResponderGrant": [Function onResponderGrant], 
"onResponderMove": [Function onResponderMove], "onResponderRelease": [Function onResponderRelease], 
"onResponderTerminate": [Function onResponderTerminate], "onResponderTerminationRequest": [Function 
onResponderTerminationRequest], "onScroll": [Function _onScroll], "onSelectionChange": [Function 
_onSelectionChange], "onStartShouldSetResponder": [Function onStartShouldSetResponder], 
"rejectResponderTermination": true, "selection": null, "style": [Array], "text": "hallo", 
"textBreakStrategy": undefined, "underlineColorAndroid": "transparent", "value": "hallo"}, 
"memoizedState": null, "mode": 8, "nextEffect": null, "pendingProps": {"accessible": true, 
"allowFontScaling": true, "autoCapitalize": "sentences", "children": undefined, "disableFullscreenUI": 
undefined, "focusable": true, "forwardedRef": null, "mostRecentEventCount": 5, "onBlur": [Function 
_onBlur], "onChange": [Function _onChange], "onChangeText": [Function onChangeText], "onClick": [Function 
onClick], "onEndEditing": [Function onEndEditing], "onFocus": [Function _onFocus], "onResponderGrant": 
[Function onResponderGrant], "onResponderMove": [Function onResponderMove], "onResponderRelease": 
[Function onResponderRelease], "onResponderTerminate": [Function onResponderTerminate], 
"onResponderTerminationRequest": [Function onResponderTerminationRequest], "onScroll": [Function 
_onScroll], "onSelectionChange": [Function _onSelectionChange], "onStartShouldSetResponder": [Function 
onStartShouldSetResponder], "rejectResponderTermination": true, "selection": null, "style": [Array], 
"text": "hallo", "textBreakStrategy": undefined, "underlineColorAndroid": "transparent", "value": 
"hallo"}, "ref": [Function forwardRef], "return": {"_debugHookTypes": null, "_debugID": 1398, 
"_debugIsCurrentlyTiming": false, "_debugNeedsRemount": false, "_debugOwner": [FiberNode], "_debugSource": 
[Object], "actualDuration": 0, "actualStartTime": 5771, "alternate": [FiberNode], "child": [Circular], 
"childExpirationTime": 0, "dependencies": null, "effectTag": 5, "elementType": [Function 
TouchableWithoutFeedback], "expirationTime": 0, "firstEffect": [Circular], "index": 0, "key": null, 
"lastEffect": [Circular], "memoizedProps": [Object], "memoizedState": [Object], "mode": 8, "nextEffect": 
null, "pendingProps": [Object], "ref": null, "return": [FiberNode], "selfBaseDuration": 0, "sibling": 
null, "stateNode": [TouchableWithoutFeedback], "tag": 1, "treeBaseDuration": 0, "type": [Function 
TouchableWithoutFeedback], "updateQueue": [Object]}, "selfBaseDuration": 0, "sibling": null, "stateNode": 
{"_children": [Array], "_internalFiberInstanceHandleDEV": [Circular], "_nativeTag": 177, "clear": 
[Function clear], "getNativeRef": [Function getNativeRef], "isFocused": [Function isFocused], 
"viewConfig": [Object]}, "tag": 5, "treeBaseDuration": 0, "type": "AndroidTextInput", "updateQueue": 
null}, "_dispatchListeners": [Function onSubmitEditing], "_targetInst": {"_debugHookTypes": null, 
"_debugID": 1400, "_debugIsCurrentlyTiming": false, "_debugNeedsRemount": false, "_debugOwner": 
{"_debugHookTypes": [Array], "_debugID": 1394, "_debugIsCurrentlyTiming": false, "_debugNeedsRemount": 
false, "_debugOwner": [FiberNode], "_debugSource": [Object], "actualDuration": 0, "actualStartTime": 5771, 
"alternate": [FiberNode], "child": [FiberNode], "childExpirationTime": 0, "dependencies": null, 
"effectTag": 517, "elementType": [Function InternalTextInput], "expirationTime": 0, "firstEffect": 
[Circular], "index": 0, "key": null, "lastEffect": [FiberNode], "memoizedProps": [Object], 
"memoizedState": [Object], "mode": 8, "nextEffect": null, "pendingProps": [Object], "ref": null, "return": 
[FiberNode], "selfBaseDuration": 0, "sibling": null, "stateNode": null, "tag": 0, "treeBaseDuration": 0, 
"type": [Function InternalTextInput], "updateQueue": [Object]}, "_debugSource": {"columnNumber": 7, 
"fileName": "C:\\A_USER\\App\\The_App\\\\node_modules\\react-
native\\Libraries\\Components\\TextInput\\TextInput.js", "lineNumber": 1111}, "actualDuration": 0, 
"actualStartTime": 5771, "alternate": {"_debugHookTypes": null, "_debugID": 1400, 
"_debugIsCurrentlyTiming": false, "_debugNeedsRemount": false, "_debugOwner": [FiberNode], "_debugSource": 
[Object], "actualDuration": 0, "actualStartTime": 149374, "alternate": [Circular], "child": null, 
"childExpirationTime": 0, "dependencies": null, "effectTag": 132, "elementType": "AndroidTextInput", 
"expirationTime": 0, "firstEffect": null, "index": 0, "key": null, "lastEffect": null, "memoizedProps": 
[Object], "memoizedState": null, "mode": 8, "nextEffect": null, "pendingProps": [Object], "ref": [Function 
forwardRef], "return": [FiberNode], "selfBaseDuration": 0, "sibling": null, "stateNode": 
[ReactNativeFiberHostComponent], "tag": 5, "treeBaseDuration": 0, "type": "AndroidTextInput", 
"updateQueue": null}, "child": null, "childExpirationTime": 0, "dependencies": null, "effectTag": 132, 
"elementType": "AndroidTextInput", "expirationTime": 0, "firstEffect": null, "index": 0, "key": null, 
"lastEffect": null, "memoizedProps": {"accessible": true, "allowFontScaling": true, "autoCapitalize": 
"sentences", "children": undefined, "disableFullscreenUI": undefined, "focusable": true, "forwardedRef": 
null, "mostRecentEventCount": 5, "onBlur": [Function _onBlur], "onChange": [Function _onChange], 
"onChangeText": [Function onChangeText], "onClick": [Function onClick], "onEndEditing": [Function 
onEndEditing], "onFocus": [Function _onFocus], "onResponderGrant": [Function onResponderGrant], 
"onResponderMove": [Function onResponderMove], "onResponderRelease": [Function onResponderRelease], 
"onResponderTerminate": [Function onResponderTerminate], "onResponderTerminationRequest": [Function 
onResponderTerminationRequest], "onScroll": [Function _onScroll], "onSelectionChange": [Function 
_onSelectionChange], "onStartShouldSetResponder": [Function onStartShouldSetResponder], 
"rejectResponderTermination": true, "selection": null, "style": [Array], "text": "hallo", 
"textBreakStrategy": undefined, "underlineColorAndroid": "transparent", "value": "hallo"}, 
"memoizedState": null, "mode": 8, "nextEffect": null, "pendingProps": {"accessible": true, 
"allowFontScaling": true, "autoCapitalize": "sentences", "children": undefined, "disableFullscreenUI": 
undefined, "focusable": true, "forwardedRef": null, "mostRecentEventCount": 5, "onBlur": [Function 
_onBlur], "onChange": [Function _onChange], "onChangeText": [Function onChangeText], "onClick": [Function 
onClick], "onEndEditing": [Function onEndEditing], "onFocus": [Function _onFocus], "onResponderGrant": 
[Function onResponderGrant], "onResponderMove": [Function onResponderMove], "onResponderRelease": 
[Function onResponderRelease], "onResponderTerminate": [Function onResponderTerminate], 
"onResponderTerminationRequest": [Function onResponderTerminationRequest], "onScroll": [Function 
_onScroll], "onSelectionChange": [Function _onSelectionChange], "onStartShouldSetResponder": [Function 
onStartShouldSetResponder], "rejectResponderTermination": true, "selection": null, "style": [Array], 
"text": "hallo", "textBreakStrategy": undefined, "underlineColorAndroid": "transparent", "value": 
"hallo"}, "ref": [Function forwardRef], "return": {"_debugHookTypes": null, "_debugID": 1398, 
"_debugIsCurrentlyTiming": false, "_debugNeedsRemount": false, "_debugOwner": [FiberNode], "_debugSource": 
[Object], "actualDuration": 0, "actualStartTime": 5771, "alternate": [FiberNode], "child": [Circular], 
"childExpirationTime": 0, "dependencies": null, "effectTag": 5, "elementType": [Function 
TouchableWithoutFeedback], "expirationTime": 0, "firstEffect": [Circular], "index": 0, "key": null, 
"lastEffect": [Circular], "memoizedProps": [Object], "memoizedState": [Object], "mode": 8, "nextEffect": 
null, "pendingProps": [Object], "ref": null, "return": [FiberNode], "selfBaseDuration": 0, "sibling": 
null, "stateNode": [TouchableWithoutFeedback], "tag": 1, "treeBaseDuration": 0, "type": [Function 
TouchableWithoutFeedback], "updateQueue": [Object]}, "selfBaseDuration": 0, "sibling": null, "stateNode": 
{"_children": [Array], "_internalFiberInstanceHandleDEV": [Circular], "_nativeTag": 177, "clear": 
[Function clear], "getNativeRef": [Function getNativeRef], "isFocused": [Function isFocused], 
"viewConfig": [Object]}, "tag": 5, "treeBaseDuration": 0, "type": "AndroidTextInput", "updateQueue": 
null}, "bubbles": undefined, "cancelable": undefined, "currentTarget": {"_children": [], 
"_internalFiberInstanceHandleDEV": {"_debugHookTypes": null, "_debugID": 1400, "_debugIsCurrentlyTiming": 
false, "_debugNeedsRemount": false, "_debugOwner": [FiberNode], "_debugSource": [Object], 
"actualDuration": 0, "actualStartTime": 5771, "alternate": [FiberNode], "child": null, 
"childExpirationTime": 0, "dependencies": null, "effectTag": 132, "elementType": "AndroidTextInput", 
"expirationTime": 0, "firstEffect": null, "index": 0, "key": null, "lastEffect": null, "memoizedProps": 
[Object], "memoizedState": null, "mode": 8, "nextEffect": null, "pendingProps": [Object], "ref": [Function 
forwardRef], "return": [FiberNode], "selfBaseDuration": 0, "sibling": null, "stateNode": [Circular], 
"tag": 5, "treeBaseDuration": 0, "type": "AndroidTextInput", "updateQueue": null}, "_nativeTag": 177, 
"clear": [Function clear], "getNativeRef": [Function getNativeRef], "isFocused": [Function isFocused], 
"viewConfig": {"Commands": [Object], "Constants": [Object], "NativeProps": [Object], "bubblingEventTypes": 
[Object], "directEventTypes": [Object], "uiViewClassName": "AndroidTextInput", "validAttributes": 
[Object]}}, "defaultPrevented": undefined, "dispatchConfig": {"phasedRegistrationNames": {"bubbled": 
"onSubmitEditing", "captured": "onSubmitEditingCapture"}}, "eventPhase": undefined, "isDefaultPrevented": 
[Function functionThatReturnsFalse], "isPropagationStopped": [Function functionThatReturnsFalse], 
"isTrusted": undefined, "nativeEvent": {"target": 177, "text": "hallo"}, "target": {"_children": [], 
"_internalFiberInstanceHandleDEV": {"_debugHookTypes": null, "_debugID": 1400, "_debugIsCurrentlyTiming": 
false, "_debugNeedsRemount": false, "_debugOwner": [FiberNode], "_debugSource": [Object], 
"actualDuration": 0, "actualStartTime": 5771, "alternate": [FiberNode], "child": null, 
"childExpirationTime": 0, "dependencies": null, "effectTag": 132, "elementType": "AndroidTextInput", 
"expirationTime": 0, "firstEffect": null, "index": 0, "key": null, "lastEffect": null, "memoizedProps": 
[Object], "memoizedState": null, "mode": 8, "nextEffect": null, "pendingProps": [Object], "ref": [Function 
forwardRef], "return": [FiberNode], "selfBaseDuration": 0, "sibling": null, "stateNode": [Circular], 
"tag": 5, "treeBaseDuration": 0, "type": "AndroidTextInput", "updateQueue": null}, "_nativeTag": 177, 
"clear": [Function clear], "getNativeRef": [Function getNativeRef], "isFocused": [Function isFocused], 
"viewConfig": {"Commands": [Object], "Constants": [Object], "NativeProps": [Object], "bubblingEventTypes": 
[Object], "directEventTypes": [Object], "uiViewClassName": "AndroidTextInput", "validAttributes": 
[Object]}}, "timeStamp": 1618571323238, "type": undefined}
```

What could it be or is there a other way to only log the value if the user does not edit the text anymore? For IOS and Android

Comment: `e => e.nativeEvent.text`

Comment: Yeah. Thank you. Would you like to post this as an answere?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

React Native's `onSubmitEditing` is returning an event instead of a plain value.

In order to access the value of the input, you have to access `e.nativeEvent.text`. So in your case it would be `value.nativeEvent.text`.

Please see all the additional options here:

https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput#onsubmitediting

Comment: Thanks for this. Worked well. I was switching between onSubmitEditing and onEndEditing